# Citrix XenServer, all packages appear to be 32bit

Tags: filesystems, xen, 32bit, citrix

I'm hoping to use Citrix XenServer for a group of 4/5 machines. One of these machines has 18TB of storage (after RAID5 is taken into account). I've installed XenServer and mkfs.ext3 is the only option. After looking through packages using yum, everything is i386. I downloaded the ISO from here;

http://www.xenserver.org/overview-xenserver-open-source-virtualization/download.html

Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: A 64-bit dom0 is on the [roadmap for 1Q2014](http://www.xenserver.org/overview-xenserver-open-source-virtualization/project-roadmap/11-product/140-q1-2014-project-activities.html).

Comment: Ah, that makes a bit more sense. I'm probably going about the storage a bit wrong. I was expecting to be able to use this machine as a xen host to run the VM and have dom0 export the 18TB via nfs to the VMs running locally along with other VMs and machines we have on our network.